# Loop through range and insert values into SQL Table

Tags: vba, excel

A set of data in Excel looking like this:

```
Test1   12345678    1906    John    GY  DFS H1C Y
Test2   12345678    1806    Jack    GY  GQ  H1C Y
Test3   12345678    1706    Kate    GY  GQ  H1C Y
Test4   12345678    1606    Sawyer  GY  GQ  H1C
```

The very last column is to check if data was already loaded to SQL Server.

I have written code to iterate through range and insert values into SQL Table. Within this code, it also checks that last column, if there is a Y, it should skip iteration and go to the next one..

It gives me an error, saying "Else without if".

```
Sub Connection()

    Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Command As ADODB.Command

    Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set Command = New ADODB.Command

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rownumber As Integer

    rownumber = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row


    Conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=[Server];Initial Catalog=[DB];User ID=[user];Password=[Password]; Trusted_Connection=no"

    Conn.Open

    Command.ActiveConnection = Conn


    For i = 1 To rownumber 'rows

        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 8).Value = "Y" Then GoTo NextIteration

        Else

        Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Database] (" & _
            "[Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4], [Col5], [Col6], [Col7])" & _
            "VALUES (" & _
            "'" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value & "'," & _
            "'" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value & "'," & _
            "'" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value & "'," & _
            "'" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value & "'," & _
            "'" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value & "'," & _
            "'" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value & "'," & _
            "'" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value & "')"

        Command.Execute
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 8).Value = "Y"
        End If
    Next i


    Conn.Close

    Set Conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am really struggling to figure out where I went wrong. The code works perfectly fine without checking if "Y" is there...

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Btw change i and rowNumber to be Long not Integer.

Comment: Ok @QHarr , I done that, still does not work. May I ask why though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

1. Use Option Explicit at the top to check for variable declarations
2. Use Long not Integer to avoid potential overflow as you are working with numbers of rows which can exceed capacity of Integer
3. If statement needs to be broken over several lines to function with Else
4. Your GoTo referenced a label, `NextIteration`, which needed adding, You need to verify this is now in the correct place.
5. Avoid calling your sub connection and use something less ambiguous for the compiler

   ```
   Public Sub My_Connection()

       Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
       Dim Command As ADODB.Command

       Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
       Set Command = New ADODB.Command

       Dim i As Long
       Dim rownumber As Long

       rownumber = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

       Conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=[Server];Initial Catalog=[DB];User ID=[user];Password=[Password]; Trusted_Connection=no"

       Conn.Open        
       Command.ActiveConnection = Conn

       For i = 1 To rownumber                       'rows

           If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 8).Value = "Y" Then

               GoTo NextIteration

           Else

               Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Database] (" & _
                                     "[Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4], [Col5], [Col6], [Col7])" & _
                                     "VALUES (" & _
                                     "'" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value & "'," & _
                                     "'" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value & "'," & _
                                     "'" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value & "'," & _
                                     "'" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value & "'," & _
                                     "'" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value & "'," & _
                                     "'" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value & "'," & _
                                     "'" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value & "')"

               Command.Execute
               ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 8).Value = "Y"
           End If

   NextIteration:

       Next i

       Conn.Close       
       Set Conn = Nothing

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: I see what I missed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add a new line after 'Then' on the first if statement or elses vba implicity closes the if statement.

Comment: Sorry.  Why not leave the content under the if statement blank instead of   GoTo NextIteration?